# Django Отношения многие ко многим

Tags: python, django

Делаю учебный пример на основе https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/

Есть модель с отношением многие ко многим

```
class Publication(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=30)


class Article(models.Model):
    headline = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    publications = models.ManyToManyField(Publication)
```

Далее если одному объекту Article запросить статусы, то все работает
    a2.publications.all()

Вопрос в том, как получить все объекты Article и каждому были прикреплены все записи Publication

попробовал так

```
articles = Article.objects.all().values('headline', 'publications__title')
```

но при связи многие ко многим я получаю дублирование articles на то кол-во раз, сколько есть в нем publications

Пока сделал так: в цикле перебрал все articles и потом создал словарь всех publications, но такое решение мне не нравится и хотелось бы получить один полноценный объект, который можно передать в представление.

Примерно что я хотел бы на языке SQL

```
SELECT headline FROM `Articles` 
INNER JOIN title on Articles.publications = Publication.id
```

SQL не проверял на правильность, но думаю идею в целом он передаст

Т.е. должен получиться список объектов, который содержит все Article и у каждого Article был список Publication

Comment: Что именно вы имеет ввиду под "как получить все объекты Article и каждому были прикреплены все записи Publication"? Вы пытаетесь снизить количество обращений к БД?

Comment: Я хотел бы сделать выборку запросом, а не в цикле добавлять данные. Обычным SQL это возможно при помощи INNER JOIN

Comment: решил данный вопрос. Я в корне не правильно подходил к решению задачи. Необходимо было получить все Articles, а в шаблоне пройтись по ним циклом и достать все Publication командой a2.publications.all - в представлении без скобок

Answer (score 0):

Если кому-то пригодится, то вот мой метод по извлечению таблички со связанными объектами "многие ко многим":

```
        def merge_values(values):
            grouped_results = itertools.groupby(values, key=lambda value: value['id'])
            merged_values = []
            for k, g in grouped_results:
                groups = list(g)
                merged_value = {}
                sub_entities_ids = {}
                for group in groups:
                    group_sub_entities = {}

                    for key, val in group.items():
                        val = str(val) if type(val) is UUID else val if not type(val) is datetime else val.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
                        if not merged_value.get(key) and key.find('__') == -1:
                            merged_value[key] = val
                        elif key.find('__') != -1:
                            key_entity = key[:key.find('__')]
                            key_entity_field = key[key.find('__') + 2:]

                            if val is None:
                                continue

                            if key_entity_field == 'id':
                                if not val in sub_entities_ids:
                                    sub_entities_ids[val] = 'Y'
                                else:
                                    group_sub_entities[key_entity] = 'N'
                                    continue
                            else:
                                if key_entity in group_sub_entities and group_sub_entities[key_entity] == 'N':
                                    continue

                            if group_sub_entities.get(key_entity) and isinstance(group_sub_entities[key_entity], dict):
                                group_sub_entities[key_entity][key_entity_field] = val
                            else:
                                group_sub_entities[key_entity] = {key_entity_field: val}

                    for sub_entity_name in group_sub_entities.keys():
                        if not merged_value.get(sub_entity_name) and group_sub_entities[sub_entity_name] != 'N':
                            merged_value[sub_entity_name] = [group_sub_entities[sub_entity_name]]
                        elif group_sub_entities[sub_entity_name] != 'N':
                            merged_value[sub_entity_name].append(group_sub_entities[sub_entity_name])

                merged_values.append(merged_value)
            return merged_values
```

Далее делаем просто:

```
merge_values(Model.objects.all().values('id', 'name', 'profiles__id', 'profiles__name', 'user_permission__id', 'user_permission__code', ...N)
```

Где profiles, user_permission - это m2m связь;

Получаю список полей необходимой модели через **[field.name for field in Model._meta.fields]**
Список полей m2m **[m2m_field.name for m2m_field in field.related_model._meta.fields for field in Model._meta.many_to_many]**

P.S Единственное замечание - в списке полей связанных объектов обязательно должен быть идентификатор 'id', иначе будут дубли